# QGIS - Chop/ Modify Selected Areas with Islands to Remove Islands

Tags: qgis, global-mapper

Are there any processing tool in QGIS to remove island/ donuts/ hole like the picture below? Similar to global mapper's "Chop/ Modify Selected Areas with Islands to Remove Islands"

Aiming for Left. I want to make it as a singular shape/object:

[image]

Comment: You are aiming for the situation on the left or on the right?

Comment: Aiming for Left. I want to make it as a singular shape/object.